Changing a username
An old Java webapp that I've inherited connects to a (dockerized) Postgres database, using a certain username olduser. Since this username was the first name of the developer who is now long gone, I wanted to rename it to a technical user. First, I renamed the user within Postgres (to newuser), which did not raise any errors. NB I renamed the existing user, I didn't create a new one, and I didn't change the password.
Next, I replaced all occurrences of olduser in the Java project (XML etc.) with newuser, and redeployed/restarted everything.
Now the log says:
ERROR [http-nio-8080-exec-4] (JDBCExceptionReporter.java:78) - FATAL: password authentication failed for user "newuser"

whereas before it was connecting fine with olduser.
Any ideas what I did wrong?

Obvious first thing to do is try connecting with psql or some other tool using "newuser" and the password you have on record

Did you notice the "NOTICE:  MD5 password cleared because of role rename"?

@jjanes I used the rename functionality within pgadmin4, which did not show such a message

As it turns out, re-entering the password of newuser in Postgres solved the issue, even though I had not touched the password:
ALTER USER newuser WITH PASSWORD 'oldpassword';


Per @jjanes comment and docs Alter Role: Because MD5-encrypted passwords use the role name as cryptographic salt, renaming a role clears its password if the password is MD5-encrypted..

@AdrianKlaver thank you for the explanation! I had used pgadmin4's GUI to rename the user, unfortunately it did not show the helpful notice

Make your life easier and use psql.

@AdrianKlaver noted
